# JSON Response with Spring 3 MVC and jQuery

Tags: json, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I have some huge trouble receiving JSON from my simple Spring Controller although I checked against many other tutorials and even the official spring blog and could not find any difference, so please help me.

So my dependencies in my project are:

- spring-context 3.2.2 RELEASE
- spring-web 3.2.2 RELEASE
- spring-webmvc 3.2.2 RELEASE
- spring-test 3.2.2 RELEASE
- junit 4.10
- servlet-api 2.5
- atmosphere-runtime 1.1.0 RC4
- logback-classic 1.0.13
- libthrift 0.9.0
- jackson-mapper-asl 1.9.12
- jackson-core-asl 1.9.12

My Controller is very simple and just generates a random UUID and returns it. It looks as follows:

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {

@RequestMapping(value="/new", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody SimpleResponse new() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    SimpleResponse sr = new SimpleResponse();
    sr.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    return sr;

    }
}
```

The model is just a simple POJO like

```
public class SimpleResponse {

private String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Configuration is done like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

<display-name>SimpleTest</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="de.tum.ibis.wsc" />

</beans>
```

So thats the server side. On the client side I have a html page with just one line of jQuery code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/Frontend/app/new", function(data) { console.log("it works"); });

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Now according to everything I have read this should work but it does not for me. If I call localhost:8080/Frontend/app/new directly in my browser I get something like this: {"id":"b46b8d67-5614-44ed-90ef-d2da14d260f6"} and Firebug tells me that the response header from the server is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(7.6.5.v20120716)
```

so content-type should be fine. Well if I now run the jquery ajax call I get the error "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data " in jquery.js and I have no cloue why. I hope anybody can help me with that. Thanks!

------ Update ------

**Firebug: jQuery error**

[image: Firebug: jQuery error]

**Firebug: All I get**

[image: Firebug: All I get]

**Firebug: This is what I get if a access the url directly**

[image: Firebug: This is what I get if a access the url directly]

Comment: Inspect the ajax request with your firebug and see the response text

Comment: I added three pictures of all that I get

Comment: I notice that in your request (direct access) you are accepting `text/html` (which is not correct), while your JSON request is asking for `application/json`. You should try to use a REST client (Firefox has an addon for it I think) and see if that's causing the problem or not. I think that your Spring controller is only mapped on text/html requests.

Comment: @DimitriM I just tried to access the URL with the REST Client plugin for firefox and it also worked just fine

Comment: Did you define a header `Accept: application/json`?

Comment: I defined a custom header with `Content-Type: application/json` and another with `Accept: application/json` and both worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try configuring `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean` in Spring XML config, see [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-content-negotiation)

Set `favorPathExtension` to `false` and update method's `@RequestMapping` like so

```
@RequestMapping(value="/new", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but did not have any effect :(

Comment: @Ralf just a wild guess - HTML page where you have your jQuery code, is it servered from within your application (i.e. is it on the same domain - localhost)? `Origin: null` in Firebug data looks suspicious.

Comment: Oh my god!!! I did the dumbest thing one can do. Somehow I was not thinking and my brain was totally turned of. I tried to call the controller running on `localhost` from a html page located on my filesystem so `file:///`. If I put the html page on the server and run the ajax call it works just fine. Shame on me. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX request, you're using

```
http://localhost:8080/Frontend/app/new
```

And your servlet declares URL "/new", you should use "/app/new" instead.

> @RequestMapping(value="/app/new", method=RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: Thansk for the answer but the /app specifies the spring dispatcher servlet as seen in web.xml <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>. So that cannot cause the problem and I am able to access it directly by calling the url so the request dispatching is correct.